# Find the field of a coin with the largest and smallest elements

Tags: probability, statistics

**Question**
You have a coin with $\{H,T\}$ heads and tails. Find the $\sigma$-field with the largest and smallest amount of elements.

The requirements for a $\sigma$-field is:

1. $a \in \sigma$-field
2. $a'$ ($a$ complement or $a$ not) $\in$ $\sigma$-field
3. $a \cup b \in \sigma$-field

**Attempt at the solution**

So wouldn't that mean the $\sigma$-field with the largest elements is:

$S = \{\emptyset, \{H\}, \{T\}, \{H,T\}\}$

Justification: Meets all requirements and contains 4 elements. The most it can contain.

And the $\sigma$-field smallest elements is:

$S: \{\emptyset, \{H,T\}\}$

Both meet the requirements of the $\sigma$-field. Can someone else verify my answer? Thanks!

Comment: Your requirements need to be stated better. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra#Definition) for more precise statements.

Answer (score 1):

Your work looks fine. In general, for any space $\Omega$ (in your example, $\Omega=\{H,T\}$), the largest $\sigma$-field is the power set of $\Omega$ (collection of all subsets of $\Omega$), and the smallest $\sigma$-field is $\{\varnothing,\Omega\}$.

Also, I think you should double check your definition of $\sigma$-field. In particular, you are missing the condition that the whole space $\Omega$ be in the $\sigma$-field, as well as closure under countable union (not just finite union).